# Search in XML-File via JS/AJAX just for 1 Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, search

I am on searching for solution almost 3 days now. All I found was about open XML find results! and display them on page. I tried to adapt this samples into my needs. But got not the result I wanted to have.

*Here XML-Sample how I have:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<preiseBau>
    <reinigungEFHETW>
        <id>1</id>
        <suchfeld>Test</suchfeld>
        <immoart>Hallo 1</immoart>
        <zimmer>1</zimmer>
        <qm>10</qm>
        <preis>100</preis>
    </reinigungEFHETW>
    <reinigungEFHETW>
        <id>2</id>
        <suchfeld>Test2</suchfeld>
        <immoart>Hallo 2</immoart>
        <zimmer>2</zimmer>
        <qm>20</qm>
        <preis>200</preis>
    </reinigungEFHETW>
    <reinigungEFHETW>
        <id>3</id>
        <suchfeld>Test3</suchfeld>
        <immoart>Hallo 3</immoart>
        <zimmer>3</zimmer>
        <qm>30</qm>
        <preis>300</preis>
    </reinigungEFHETW>  
</preiseBau>
```

*This is the script I am trying to find and append to a field:*
strSearchterm = str1+str2+str3+str4

```
// XML Datei laden
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../js/myxml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

    $(xml).find('reinigungEFHETW')
            .find("suchfeld:contains('"+strSearchterm+"')")
            .each(function(){
    var x = $(this).find('preis').val()
           alert (x)
    }
```

Itried with this too:

```
strSearchterm = str1+str2+str3+str4

    // XML Datei laden
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../js/myxml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

        $(xml).find("suchfeld:contains('"+strSearchterm+"')")
                .each(function(){
        alert ($(this).find('preis').text())
               //alert (xl)
        })
        }
```

*What I want to do:*
Build a searchterm; open xml-file, find there searchterm (unique!) in "suchfeld" and append the text in "preis".

What's wrong with my code? Searching in web/youtube, I could not find *the* solution for finding 1 data!
Hope there somebody can give me the "kick" in the right direction :D
Best regards
Michael

Comment: There is no `suchfeld ` that contains `str1+str2+str3+str4`!

Comment: how do we know  it's a code problem and not a search term issue? Are cases the same in terms and values? Are you placing spaces correctly?

Comment: There is a code before str1+str2+str3+str4 in which str1, str2,str3 and str4 are defined. Having there no problems I haven't inculeded that into my question to shorten my code!
I have tried this with alert (strSearchterm). so there can't be a problem
I am using this in SEBLOD field included into joomla 3.x  If I would use semikolon ";" after the lines I get failure and side is not shown correctly.

Comment: Need to create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: to replicate the problem just use: var strSearchterm = "Test". I think this will give same result!

Comment: 100 200 300 is what you expect?

Comment: BUT: If found "Test" than 100, When Searchterm is "Test2" than 200, and When Searchterm is "Test3" than 300!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with :

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <preiseBau> <reinigungEFHETW> <id>1</id> <suchfeld>Test</suchfeld> <immoart>Hallo 1</immoart> <zimmer>1</zimmer> <qm>10</qm> <preis>100</preis> </reinigungEFHETW> <reinigungEFHETW> <id>2</id> <suchfeld>Test2</suchfeld> <immoart>Hallo 2</immoart> <zimmer>2</zimmer> <qm>20</qm> <preis>200</preis> </reinigungEFHETW> <reinigungEFHETW> <id>3</id> <suchfeld>Test3</suchfeld> <immoart>Hallo 3</immoart> <zimmer>3</zimmer> <qm>30</qm> <preis>300</preis> </reinigungEFHETW> </preiseBau>';

var strSearchterm = 'Test';

$(xml).find("suchfeld:contains('"+strSearchterm+"')")
    .each(function(index, xmlNode){
  $("p").append( $(xmlNode).siblings('preis').text() + " ")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy!
But it is not that I wanted to have. may be you undersstand what I mean here: http://www.maksy-clean.de/angebote.
I want to have the search result in field Preis!

Comment: @Jeremy, you nearly have the answer. Just change `$(xmlNode).text()` to `$(xmlNode).siblings('preis').text()`

Comment: Oh right, we were looking for 'Preis'! I forgot that detail. Thanks :)

Comment: Still have problems to append!!! In FireFox says something wrong: http://prntscr.com/6l6oq0

Comment: I have no error at all in Firefox or Chrome with the code I posted above. Your errors says "Not well formed"  so you may have a problem with your XML structure. Try an XML validator : http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: XML-File has no errors: http://prntscr.com/6l6toi

:/ I do not know where to look.... :((

Comment: The problem does not come from my code. I guess you do something else for this "not well-formed" error to appear. I think that's worth another question. By the way, why are you using XML and not JSON? It would be way easier... no text to parse etc.

Comment: The point is I have an Excel file with 4 different sheets and different prices. In sum 820. So I wrote a VBA Code to make another table. This sheet into xml data. I thought it is much easier if there are some price changes. Just make a "klick" and all datas will be changed. Export into xml and upload into web folder!
I do not know how todo this all using JSON :/

Comment: Okay, makes sense. But I don't know what else in your code causes this error.

Comment: I solved the Problem so far.... But still can't apend to my field in form (of seblod). 
ANother question, how can I prevent that xml-file is "opened" many times, but opened once only?

Comment: You really have a lot of issues with your code. The XML file shouldn't be called more that once, from the code you posted in your original question. There may be some loop or some repeating condition around, I can't be sure.